# Unable to configure CName in Azure APIM consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have Azure subscription. We have configured APIM service consumption plan. We are unable to configure CNAME under Gateway option of APIM screen. It gives error with correlation Id and says contact Azure support team.

Comment: How about contacting the azure support team?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your custom cname is already binded to API Management default hostname before calling update. There is a fix which will show exact error message in future.

Comment: yes, it already bounded to default hostname. We are not updating, we selected New

Comment: What is the service name

Answer (score 0):

Azure API Management Consumption Tier is built over Azure App Services which is built over a framework different than the framework the other APIM tiers built over and called (Antares).

This actually requires you first to register a CNAME record at your service provider before adding a custom domain (upload the cert) at the API Management Level.

If the you are trying to use the custom domain api.xyz.ie and your service name is abcd, the CNAME should be registered as follows:

```
CName api.xyz.ie abcd.azure-api.net
```

This procedure most probably is just to verify your ownership for the domain.